# Error when importing csv file

Tags: excel, csv, import, vba

I have a macro that imports csv-files into sheets with the same name in a workbook. All the csv files end with ".csv" except for one file which ends with ".CSV". The macro is importing the csv files that end with ".csv" fine. But when it encounters the csv file with ".CSV" it adds a new sheet. I think it's a matter of deactiviting the case sensivity (and I've tried) but I'm not sure. Here's the code:

```
Private Sub importOrUpdate(opr$)
    Dim csvFile, csvArr
    Dim wsCSV As Worksheet, wsImport As Worksheet
    Dim importFolder$, cnt%, i%
    Dim csvName$, idx%, arr, shName$
    Dim processed$

U.Start
processed = "|"

csvArr = selectFiles

For i = 0 To UBound(csvArr)
    'Workbooks.Open csvArr(i), False, True
    Call importToTempSheet(csvArr(i))
    Set wsCSV = Tempsheet

    idx = InStrRev(csvArr(i), "\") + 1
    csvName = Mid(csvArr(i), idx)
    csvName = Replace(csvName, ".csv", "")
    arr = Split(csvName, "_")

    If UBound(arr) = 2 Then
        shName = arr(1) & "_" & arr(2)
    Else
        shName = csvName
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsImport = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wsImport Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add before:=Sheet14
        Set wsImport = ActiveSheet
        wsImport.Tab.Color = 5296274
        wsImport.Name = shName
        Call import(wsCSV, wsImport)
    ElseIf opr = "Update" Then
        Call update(wsCSV, wsImport)
    ElseIf InStr(1, processed, "|" & shName & "|", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Call update(wsCSV, wsImport)
    Else
        Call import(wsCSV, wsImport)
    End If

    Call updateFormula(wsImport)
    processed = processed & shName & "|"
    cnt = cnt + 1
    'wsCSV.Parent.Close False
Next

Sheet14.Activate
U.Finish

MsgBox cnt & " files imported/updated", vbInformation

End Sub

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub importToTempSheet(filePath)
Dim lRow&

Tempsheet.Cells.Clear

Dim wsCSV As Worksheet
Workbooks.Open filePath, False, True
Set wsCSV = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

lRow = wsCSV.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

wsCSV.Range("A1:A" & lRow).Copy
Tempsheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
wsCSV.Parent.Close

Tempsheet.Range("A1:A" & lRow).TextToColumns Tempsheet.Range("A1"), xlDelimited, xlTextQualifierNone, False, False, True, False, False

With Tempsheet
    .Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    convertToDate .Range("A2", .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
End With
End Sub

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Private Function selectFiles()
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Title = "Select CSV Files"
        .ButtonName = "Select"
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.csv"
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
        .Show

    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        End
    Else
        Dim csvArr, i%
        ReDim csvArr(.SelectedItems.Count - 1)
        For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
            csvArr(i - 1) = .SelectedItems(i)
        Next
        selectFiles = csvArr
    End If
End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the replace

try..

```
csvName = Replace(LCase(csvName), ".csv", "")
```

or use two replaces...

```
csvName = Replace(csvName, ".csv", "")
csvName = Replace(csvName, ".CSV", "")
```

Comment: Tried the second option initially. Don't know why it didn't Work. Anyway, it is working now. Thank you, The_Barman!